# Binding model in custom directive using this keyword

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Students.html

```
<div class="row">
    <student info="ui.Ram"></student>
</div>
```

Student.directive Template

```
<h1>{{ui.name}}</h1>
```

Route Config

```
app.config(urlRouter);
     
       function urlRouter($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   
    $routeProvider
       .when('/students', {
           templateUrl: 'app/views/students.html',
           controller: 'prodCtrl',
           controllerAs: 'ui'
       })
       }
```

Custom Directive

```
     app.directive('student', "student");

    function student() {
        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = 'E';
        directive.templateUrl = "Student.directive.html";
        directive.scope = {
           ui : "=name"
        }
        return directive;
     });
```

Controller

```
     app.controller('StudentController', StudentController);
     
     function StudentController($scope) {
        
        $scope.Ram= {};
        $scope.Ram.name = "Mahesh";
        
     };
```

When I do this way, name ("Mahesh") is reflected in UI.

I am thinking to do the same without injecting $scope in the controller.
Something like this.

```
      function StudentController() {
        var  vm = this;
        vm.Ram= {};
        vm.Ram.name = "Mahesh";
        
       return vm;
     };
```

But the value is not reflecting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `controller as` syntax in view to do that:

```
  <div ng-app = "app" ng-controller = "StudentController as ctrl">
     <student name = "ctrl.Ram"></student>
  </div>
```

Comment: THANKS!! meanwhile I tried the same but the other scenario that I have it's still not rendering

Comment: Create a plunker that reproduces problem

Comment: Sorry!!  I update my question here itself,please check